# Automatic location detection in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, networking, location, privacy, zipcode

A technical and legal question - what's the best rails gem to auto-detect location of a web visitor via e.g. IP? Down to granularity of state.

And is this an illegal privacy breach?  Why do some sites auto-detect location and others ask for manual zip code input?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some sort of IP-to-location translation database, like this one:

http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location

[Update: free version is here: [http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity]](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity)

The reason some auto-detect and others don't is a question of reliability. You can't guarantee the IP you're seeing is the actual end users IP (proxies/VPNs/etc cause problems) so while it's fine for general use, it's not practical if you're doing something for example with billing or calculating shipping costs.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby Geocoder, check it [here](http://www.rubygeocoder.com/). It goes down to the granularity of city, well, it depends on many factors, but generally it works well. [This](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder) Railscast shows some use cases.